# Firestore Compound Queries inside foreach statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like some help if possible, I want to do a Firestore compound query inside 2 foreach statements as I need to get all relevant data back that matches the contents in the arrays being looped through.

```
arenas.forEach((arenasElement: any) => {
    sports.forEach((sportsElement: any) => {
        firebaseAdmin.firestore().collection('leagues')
            .where('arenaUid', '==', arenasElement)
            .where('sportUid', '==', sportsElement)
            .get()
            .then((querySnapshot: any) => {
                querySnapshot.docs.map((element: any) => {
                    leaguesArray.push(element.data())
                })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
                res.send(error)
            })
    })
})
```

I need all the relevant results to be stored in the array as all of them are objects & I want to return that array when all of the queries are finished executing as I need all the data.

I've tried looking at promises & wrapping it but I had no success in the matter.

Any help would be gladly appreciated!

EDIT: The above got answered with below but I am struggling with another function I have

```
export const getSports = firebaseFunctions.https.onRequest((req: any, res: any) => {
cors(req, res, () => {
    let sportsUidArray: any = []
    let sportsArray: any = []
    let arenas: any = []
    let promises: any = []

    arenas = req.body.arenas

    arenas.forEach((arenasElement: any) => {
        promises.push(
            firebaseAdmin.firestore()
                .collection('leagues')
                .where('arenaUid', '==', arenasElement)
                .orderBy('title')
                .get()
        )
    })

    Promise.all(
        promises
    ).then((querySnapshots: any) => {
        querySnapshots.forEach((snapshotElement: any) => {
            snapshotElement.docs.map((element: any) => {
                sportsUidArray.push(element.data().sportUid)
            })
        })

        sportsUidArray = Array.from(new Set(sportsUidArray))

        promises = []

        sportsUidArray.forEach((sportIdElement: any) => {
            promises.push(
                firebaseAdmin.firestore()
                    .collection('sports')
                    .doc(sportIdElement)
                    .get()
            )
        })

        Promise.all(
            promises
        ).then((querySnapshots2: any) => {
            querySnapshots2.forEach((snapshotElement: any) => {
                /* Issue with line below */
                snapshotElement.docs.map((sportsElement: any) => {
                    sportsArray.push({ id: sportsElement.id, data: sportsElement.data() })
                })
            })

            res.send(sportsArray)
        }).catch((err: any) => {
            res.send(err)
            console.error(err)
        })
    }).catch((err: any) => {
        res.send(err)
        console.error(err)
    })
})
```

})

Error I'm receiving from Firebase:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Comment: Can you not simply get all documents from the `leagues` collection?

Comment: There are too many, I want to only return specific ones relevant to to the id's in the arena & sports arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var promises = [];
arenas.forEach((arenasElement: any) => {
    sports.forEach((sportsElement: any) => {
        promises.push(firebaseAdmin.firestore().collection('leagues')
            .where('arenaUid', '==', arenasElement)
            .where('sportUid', '==', sportsElement)
            .get());
    })
})
Promise.all(promises).then((snapshots: any) => {
    var leaguesArray = [];
    snapshots.forEach((querySnapshot: any) => {
        querySnapshot.docs.map((element: any) => {
            leaguesArray.push(element.data())
        })
    })
    res.send(JSON.stringify(leaguesArray));
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
    res.send(error)
})
```

You'll note that my changes are pretty small:

1. Create an array of promises with the code that load the data.
2. Put the code of you `then()` into a single `then()` that fires after all data has loaded (with `Promise.all()`).

Comment: I'll give it a whirl & get back to you!

Comment: It worked thanks, but I have another issue with a separate function if you don't mind looking at it as well?

Made an edit above!