# Is it a bad thing to observe many path in Cloud Firestore on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My DataBase looks like this.

```
-Users
 -uid
  -roomID
  -roomID
  -roomID

-ChatRooms
 -roomID
  -chats
 -roomID
  -chats
```

and I want to observe all chat rooms that user is in. so when the user has 100 chat rooms it means that I will run 100 observers. Is it a bad thing to run that many observers?

Comment: Do you have any other option ?

Comment: See if this helps? [Firestore Compound Queries inside foreach statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48641090/firestore-compound-queries-inside-foreach-statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on how you define "bad".  Having many observers is not necessarily a problem.  Have many observers on queries that are each generating a lot of changes could cause a lot of data to be consumed by your app, which could make your app appear slow from the perspective of the user.

Only you can guess how much data can be consumed by your observers - we have no way of knowing from reading your question.  You will have to estimate or measure this on your own.

Also be aware that you will have to pay for any document reads that occur while those observers are active.  If that's fine by you, then there's no problem.